# Interacting with other applications (like clicking a button)

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation

I'm trying to automate many repetitive tasks at work and this small problem got me stumped.

We are using an application for printing out labels for online-orders, the process is like this.

1. Click the order
2. Check order details and Click "Finish"
3. *5 seconds of the program calculating*
4. Confirm that you wish to print the label
5. Label prints and you're done

On busy days we gotta go trough this process for over 500 orders, because this task consumes a lot of useless time because of step 3. The user has to wait those 5 seconds before being able to click the Print button. Let's say we have 500 orders, that's 500 times 5 seconds, that's about 40 minutes. The entire sending process costs 2 hours, so 33% of all time is lost because of people waiting to click the button.

I'm trying to find a way to automate step 4 so users can stop interacting with the application after completing step 2.

**So is there a way using C# to click a button in another form from a different application?** The event has to trigger when the confirmation screen pops up. Note that this confirmation screen is not the default windows printing dialog, but a part of the application, so no messing with the preferences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should look into the UI scripting tools like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) instead of writing your own.

Comment: Yeah I guess 3rd party tools are fine too. Let me just try them out.

Comment: Thanks! I used AutoIt, it's an easy to learn language and it gets the job done. Now I just start the macro up, it waits for the desired window to open, presses the enter key and then repeats the process.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to click a button on the form with the User32 dll if you know the forms handle.

I use [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) to look up the methods

In order to work out whether the screen has opened / closed you could create a windows hook that fires when a screen opens or closes. You will need to have a C++ library to do this as its not possible in c#, but you only need to create a small C++ assembly then reference it from your c#. You can check the title of a window when it opens to see if its the window you want, then you can get the window handle and see when it closes.

Some information on how to implement hooks can be found here.

http://www.voidnish.com/Articles/ShowArticle.aspx?code=manipwindows

The C++ assembly I used once is called GlobalCBTHook.

Here is another link from code project that shows global window hooks

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx

**The link above is the one that got me started**