# Write on a VFP textbox from within c#

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

In an application that I'm working on, I have the need to write in a VFP application's textbox and then to click a button (VFP too).

The application that I'm working on written in c#. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks, i'm completely lost.

Comment: So you're trying to automate a VFP program externally using C#?

Comment: Yes sir @D Stanley, is exactly what i want to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interacting with other applications (like clicking a button)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408547/interacting-with-other-applications-like-clicking-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that would be to use native Windows messages as communication between both applications. On the C# end you would use P/Invoke to call [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) with a custom message, passin the data to the VFP Window, while on the VFP end you would use [BINDEVENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w42fek8t(v=vs.80).aspx) to receive those messages and act accordingly (this one requires VFP9)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a Timer in the VFP application, than waits for a external signal, like a presence of text file. The C# program will have to create and populate that file

```
* In the Timer event (within VFP application) just ask for that file:

this.Enabled=.f.

if file("C:\c_program_params.txt") 

 * many kinds of ways to interact with that file
 lnH=fopen("C:\c_program_params.txt")
 ...

 * or
 lcContent=filetostr("C:\c_program_params.txt")

endif

this.Enabled=.t.
```